# is it possible to make transparent box shows what's behind opaque background

Tags: css, transparency, opacity

I'm working on an image cropping project. I made an overlay above the image. and a moving transparent box above them all.

I need to show a part of the image through the moving transparent box, although there is an overlay between them.

```js
var imgCropper = document.getElementById("imgCropper");
dragElement(imgCropper);
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (imgCropper) {
    imgCropper.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#frame{
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  position:relative; 
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

#overLay{  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

#imgCropper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  background-color::transparent;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  cursor: move;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
    
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
<div id="overLay">
<div id="imgCropper">
  Crop Image
</div>
</div>
<img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61r8Bx96OBS._AC_SL1500_.jpg" width="700" />
</div>
```

please help ..
How can I do that? to see the image through the moving box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the overlay a big box-shadow instead:

```js
var imgCropper = document.getElementById("imgCropper");

dragElement(imgCropper);

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  
  if (imgCropper) {
    imgCropper.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#frame{
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  position:relative; 
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

#overLay{  
  position: absolute;
  inset:0; /* to simplify left/top/width/height */
  z-index: 2;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#imgCropper {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 200vmax rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  cursor: move;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
    
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="overLay">
    <div id="imgCropper">
      Crop Image
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61r8Bx96OBS._AC_SL1500_.jpg" width="700" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you @TemaniAfif :)